# How to specify extension for the files for external table in?

Tags: hive

I have an external table in hive. It is generating file names without any extension. How can I force Hive to add extension (e.g. .tsv) to the files ? Is there any option in the create table statement?

Answer (score -1):

You can run it directly from the command line, give it a shot

```
hive -e 'select columns from table' > /<Location>/<Filename>.tsv
```

Comment: so basically we can't tell hive to have the output files certain extension ?